# Different solutions to the same system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, maple

I want to solve a real homogeneous system of linear equations represented by this matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}0&2&2&7&1&0\\1&0&1&3&1&0\\-1&2&1&4&0&0\end{bmatrix}

The reduced echelon form is:
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&3&1&0\\0&1&1&7/2&1/2&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

Since I have used Maple to verify my answer, I know that the above matrix is correct. Now comes my question. When deriving the parameterized solution from the reduced echelon form, I want to define the free variables as:
\begin{align*}
x3=t1
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
x4=t2
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
x5=t3
\end{align*}

Then the solution has to satisfy the following equations:
\begin{align*}
x1+t1+3t2+t3=0 \leftrightarrow\ x1=-t1-3t2-t3
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
x2+t1+(7/2)t2+(1/2)t3=0 \leftrightarrow\ x2=-t1-(7/2)t2-(1/2)t3
\end{align*}

Thus the parameterized solution satisfy:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}x1\\x2\\x3\\x4\\x5\end{bmatrix}=t1\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+t2\begin{bmatrix}-3\\-7/2\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t3\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1/2\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}t1,t2,t3\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

However, when I solve the system in Maple, I get this:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}x1\\x2\\x3\\x4\\x5\end{bmatrix}=t1\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\0\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix}+t2\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix}+t3\begin{bmatrix}4\\0\\0\\1\\-7\end{bmatrix}t1,t2,t3\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

Clearly, this is the solution I will get if I define the free variables as:
\begin{align*}
x2=t1
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
x3=t2
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
x4=t3
\end{align*}

Since the solution then has to satisfy:
\begin{align*}
t1+t2+(7/2)t3+(1/2)x5=0 \leftrightarrow\ x5=-2t1-2t2-7t3
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
x1+t2+3t3+x5=0 \leftrightarrow\ x1=-t2-3t3-x5=-t2-3t3-(-2t1-2t2-7t3)=2t1+t2+4t3
\end{align*}

Are both solutions correct? If yes, does it mean that the three vectors in the two different solutions respectively spans the same vector space with respect to different bases? Also, I would really like to know why Maple does this? What is the advantage of choosing other free variables than those you normally choose?

Comment: You mention how Maple did it. But you don't show exactly what commands you used. It is very unclear.

Comment: I used the LinearSolve command.

Comment: For the mathematical part: yes, both solutions give the same vector space, so the three given vectors span the same vector space and are just different bases for it. For the Maple part: I don't know why Maple chose exactly these three variables, because I don't know anything about Maple - but there is in general no rule as to which free variables one should choose. The only thing you can try to achieve with your choice of free variable is that the resulting solution looks "nice" and has "easy" numbers in the basis vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to linear algebra, so I was a bit confused. After posting my question, I tried to express each vector in my own solution as a linear combination of the Maple solution. Since it was possible, it made me clear that the two solutions span the same vector space.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to make Maple to use your choices of free variables, how? Let us rewrite what you are looking for mathematically. What you are asking can be written as a new linear system.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & \frac{7}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
x_5
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
t_1\\
t_2\\
t_3\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the Maple code using the same `LinearSolve` command of the `LinearAlgebra` package that you have used is the following.

```
A := Matrix([ [0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0,1], [1,0,1,3,1], [0,1,1,7/2,1/2], [0,0,0,0,0] ]);
b := < t__1, t__2, t__3, 0, 0, 0 >;
LinearAlgebra:-LinearSolve( A, b );
```

The output is exactly what you found manually.

[image]